# I have an unbound datagrid and it should not permit the user to leave the cell being edited if the value is null

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How do I do this? Or at least how do I validate the cell's value during edit? I've been using the CellEndEdit Event and using this code as its condition

```
if dgvwCalibRef.Item("ReferenceValue", dgvwCalibRef.CurrentRow.Index).FormattedValue = Nothing Then
'Dont leave cell
End if
```

So what's the specific code to not let the user leave the cell?

Answer (score 1):

To do so you should use Validation on Editform of the GridView. If you are using Standard ASP.net GridView then Use `Template Field` for validation settings implementation.

follow this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb426882.aspx) to know more about this. have an idea from this and implement in Vb.net..

hope this help you..